# Installing Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 for.net

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am using the above API, within visual studio, which I installed using the NuGet package manager.

I have successfully written a web application, which retrieves Google analytics data, running on my desktop.

I am now having problems installing that web application on the server. Do I need to install any Google API or packages on the server and if so how?

Currently, I have just done what I have always done-created a folder in IIS, copied over the folder structure and converted it to an application.

However, I am receiving the following error:-
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) And it highlights the following:-

using  Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4;

Any ideas?

Thanks